# twitter api oauth/authenticate shows nothing to see here

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

It used to work till yesterday. Suddenly i am facing this problem in my app.
When user clicks on login with twitter button i cam calling this end point

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxx
```

then it shows Nothing to see here page. Any changes in twitter not sure. I have been searching for this problem from last 2 hours.
I tried changing the `oauth_token` to some test app still i see `nothing to see here` page from twitter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://api.twitterstat.us/incidents/c1qxf8zk63tg) (current as of 10th May 2022) on the Twitter API. Further discussion [on the Twitter developer forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-when-authorize-twitter-nothing-to-see-here/170967/).